# How to have a panel take up the whole page?

Tags: extjs

How would I modify this snippet from the tutorial

```
Ext.get(document.body).update('<div id="test"></div>');
new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: 'test',
    width: '200px',
    title: 'My Title',
    html: 'My HTML content',
});
```

so that the example panel took up all available space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        title: 'My Title',
        html: 'My HTML content'
    }]
});
```

Comment: You rock. Didn't know about Viewport.

Comment: :) This little library is full of powerful surprises. You will have a good time learning new things and a lot of wow moments for a long time to come.

Comment: I hope Ext4 removes the Viewport class and just adopts the fullscreen property like sencha touch.